# How to locate workflow in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, 2016, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I don't really know where to begin but I have a user that received a email (notification) from 'spsadmin'. I am assuming this was an auto notification setup via workflow but for the life of me, I cannot locate that workflow!

I have searched in SPD and OOB workflows that are listed for the possible lists, libraries etc. but I don't see anything. The title of the notification states SP version history report... not sure if that can direct me somewhere.

Please help?

Comment: I was unsuccessful in locating anything under alerts or workflows.... I used a powershell script to list all workflows and alerts for that site collection but nothing. Also, the auto notification has an attachment with everything its pulling and its pulling info from a few subsites lists... any idea how this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the Alert for the document library. Please check the Alert in the document library.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not an Alert as this notification picked up info from multiple libraries under one of our site collections. Unsure how this was possible....